# Dash and hyphen usage in Spanish

Tags: ortografía, puntuación, símbolos

English uses at least two types of [dashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) (en dash and em dash) along with [hyphens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen), and there are (fairly complex, in my opinion) rules on when and how each should be used. What types of dashes or hyphens appear in Spanish? What are the rules governing their usage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Spanish names for the hyphen, en-dash and em-dash are *guión*, *semiraya* o *raya menor*, and *raya*, respectively. In Spanish, the en-dash is not widely used although, due to English influence, its use has become rather common nowadays.

The *raya* (em-dash) usually indicates separation; for example, it signals interventions of different  characters in a dialogue and it also can be used to signal a new item in a list. The *raya* is also used to avoid repeating a word or a group of words.

On the other hand, the *guión* (hyphen) usually indicates union: of two words as in *científico-técnico*, of suffixes and words, as in *intra-aórtico*, and it is also used, as the hyphen, at the end of a line to indicate that a word will continue in the next line. The *guión* is also used between numbers forming an interval, as in *pág. 178-185*.

For more information, see the entries for [guión](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=guion2%20o%20gui%F3n) and [raya](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=raya) in the *Diccionarion panhispánico de dudas*.

The following image shows a comparison of the three signs as produced by LaTeX using the palatino font at a font size of 80pt (the letters were included only to show the position of the symbols with respect to the text baseline):

[image]

Comment: Spanish also uses a "quote dash" (that's the Unicode name I think) for dialog. It's a long one like the em dash but in Unicode the two are separate I believe.

Comment: @hippietrail: in my answer I mentioned the use of the *raya* for dialogue.

Comment: Other names are "en dash"="guión medio o corto"; "em dash"="guión largo"; and I didn't knew that "hypen" existed.

Answer (score 4):

Exceptionally well typeset materials will use anen-dash to signal a brief break in dialog which is introduced with an m-dash.  I don't see it in a lot of publishers, but it works really well.

—Yo me llamo... –murmuró el niño– Emilio Sánchez Pérez.

In either case, whereas in English style will vary as to whether you put a space or not on both sides of the dash (but you do the same on both sides), in Spanish, you can tell whether a dash is opening/closing by where the space is.

texto y más texto —y más texto… *<--opening*
texto y más texto— y más texto… *<--closing*